# PHP get DNS records without caching

Tags: php, dns, records

Does anyone know how its possible to retrieve the DNS records for a domain.

I have been using php and this function: `dns_get_record` to do this so far but have realized that this command gets cached DNS records and therefore not the up to date information.

Does anyone know a way around this in PHP or some other language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to use [Net_DNS](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_DNS) PEAR Package.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need that? DNS records doesn't change that often, and bypassing local cache will only slow queries down (especially if you start making recursive ones), with no real gain.

If you do need that, find or write a DNS resolver that can make recursive queries.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not a "polite fix" but from php you can also call system commands and shell scripts:

i.e:

```
$ host -t ns stackoverflow.com
stackoverflow.com name server cf-dns02.stackoverflow.com.
stackoverflow.com name server cf-dns01.stackoverflow.com.
```

So:

```
<?php
   echo '<pre>';

   $last_line = system('ls', $retval);

   echo '
    </pre>
    last line: ' . $last_line . '
    return value: ' . $retval;
?>
```